# Error : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

On starting up the spring boot application I get this error , but I am able to send the messages and also consume them . It's just on booting up the application.

Spring boot version 2.7.11 and Kafka version installed kafka_2.13-3.4.0

```
2023-05-10 17:17:18.359  INFO 15852 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.1.2
    2023-05-10 17:17:18.364  INFO 15852 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: f8c67dc3ae0a3265
    2023-05-10 17:17:18.364  INFO 15852 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1683719238355
    2023-05-10 17:17:48.371  INFO 15852 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Disconnecting from -2 and revoking 1 node assignment(s) because the node is taking too long to become ready.
    2023-05-10 17:17:48.372  INFO 15852 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Client requested disconnect from node -2
    2023-05-10 17:17:48.377  INFO 15852 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 29948ms, elapsed time since send: 29948ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
    2023-05-10 17:17:48.381  INFO 15852 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed
    
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata
    
    2023-05-10 17:17:48.407 ERROR 15852 --- [  restartedMain] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics
    
    org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$10(KafkaAdmin.java:423) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1425) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.checkPartitions(KafkaAdmin.java:402) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addOrModifyTopicsIfNeeded(KafkaAdmin.java:298) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:201) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:171) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
```

Comment: Please show your code and configs as a [mcve]